# BeautifulSoup "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was web-scraping [weather-searched Google](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&ei=coGHXPWEIouUr7wPo9ixoAg&q=%EC%9D%BC%EB%B3%B8%20%E6%A1%9C%E5%B7%9D%E5%B8%82%E7%9C%9F%E5%A3%81%E7%94%BA%E5%8F%A4%E5%9F%8E%20%EB%82%B4%EC%9D%BC%20%EB%82%A0%EC%94%A8&oq=%EC%9D%BC%EB%B3%B8%20%E6%A1%9C%E5%B7%9D%E5%B8%82%E7%9C%9F%E5%A3%81%E7%94%BA%E5%8F%A4%E5%9F%8E%20%EB%82%B4%EC%9D%BC%20%EB%82%A0%EC%94%A8&gs_l=psy-ab.3...232674.234409..234575...0.0..0.251.929.0j6j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......35i39.yu0YE6lnCms) with bs4, and Python can't find a `<span>` tag when there is one. How can I solve this problem?

I tried to find this `<span>` with the `class` **and** the `id`, but both failed.

```html
<div id="wob_dcp">
    <span class="vk_gy vk_sh" id="wob_dc">Clear with periodic clouds</span>    
</div>
```

Above is the HTML code I was trying to scrape in the [page](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PDzaQ3MCPCnRxHLcEsdEI9tUhDOQauN9/view?usp=sharing):

```py
response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?hl=ja&ei=coGHXPWEIouUr7wPo9ixoAg&q=%EC%9D%BC%EB%B3%B8+%E6%A1%9C%E5%B7%9D%E5%B8%82%E7%9C%9F%E5%A3%81%E7%94%BA%E5%8F%A4%E5%9F%8E+%EB%82%B4%EC%9D%BC+%EB%82%A0%EC%94%A8&oq=%EC%9D%BC%EB%B3%B8+%E6%A1%9C%E5%B7%9D%E5%B8%82%E7%9C%9F%E5%A3%81%E7%94%BA%E5%8F%A4%E5%9F%8E+%EB%82%B4%EC%9D%BC+%EB%82%A0%EC%94%A8&gs_l=psy-ab.3...232674.234409..234575...0.0..0.251.929.0j6j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......35i39.yu0YE6lnCms')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

tomorrow_weather = soup.find('span', {'id': 'wob_dc'}).text
```

But failed with this code, the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sungn_000\Desktop\weather.py", line 23, in <module>
    tomorrow_weather = soup.find('span', {'id': 'wob_dc'}).text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Please solve this error.

Comment: Please post a valid url of the page instead of a micro-image. Thank you!

Comment: Still cannot reproduce it: https://ibb.co/zJM1svX

Comment: You can use Chrome.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either with chrome. Is it supposed to get an actual page or just the search results? That id is not present when I inspect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because the weather section is rendered by the browser via JavaScript. So when you use `requests` you only get the HTML content of the page which doesn't have what you need.
You should use for example `selenium` (or `requests-html`) if you want to parse page with elements rendered by web browser.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
response = session.get('https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&ei=coGHXPWEIouUr7wPo9ixoAg&q=%EC%9D%BC%EB%B3%B8%20%E6%A1%9C%E5%B7%9D%E5%B8%82%E7%9C%9F%E5%A3%81%E7%94%BA%E5%8F%A4%E5%9F%8E%20%EB%82%B4%EC%9D%BC%20%EB%82%A0%EC%94%A8&oq=%EC%9D%BC%EB%B3%B8%20%E6%A1%9C%E5%B7%9D%E5%B8%82%E7%9C%9F%E5%A3%81%E7%94%BA%E5%8F%A4%E5%9F%8E%20%EB%82%B4%EC%9D%BC%20%EB%82%A0%EC%94%A8&gs_l=psy-ab.3...232674.234409..234575...0.0..0.251.929.0j6j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......35i39.yu0YE6lnCms')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

tomorrow_weather = soup.find('span', {'id': 'wob_dc'}).text
print(tomorrow_weather)
```

Output:

```
pawel@pawel-XPS-15-9570:~$ python test.py
Clear with periodic clouds
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! With `requests-html`, it finally worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(a)
>>> a
'<div id="wob_dcp">\n    <span class="vk_gy vk_sh" id="wob_dc">Clear with periodic clouds</span>    \n</div>'
>>> soup.find("span", id="wob_dc").text
'Clear with periodic clouds'
```

Try this out.

Comment: Obviously this works, but this is not the answer to the question. He requires it using `requests`.

Comment: If you inspect the response.content of request.get you won't find span in the content. It is because Javascript rendering the HTML and you don't get what you intending.

Answer (score 0):

It's **not** rendered via JavaScript as [pawelbylina](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55352215/15164646) mentioned, and you don't have to use `requests-html` or `selenium` since everything needed is in the HTML, and it will slow down the scraping process a lot because of page rendering.

It could be because there's no [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/User_agent) specified thus Google blocks your request and you receiving a different HTML with some sort of error because the [default `requests` `user-agent` is python-requests](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent). Google understands it and blocks a request since it's not the "real" user visit. [Checks what's your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent).

Pass `user-agent` intro request headers:

```py
headers = {
  "User-Agent":
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

requests.get("YOUR_URL", headers=headers)
```

You're looking for this, use [`select_one()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to grab just one element:

```py
soup.select_one('#wob_dc').text
```

Have a look at [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to grab `CSS` selectors by clicking on the desired elements in your browser.

---

Code and [full example that scrapes more in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Search-Weather-Answer-Box-bs4-python-serpapi#bs4_result.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
  "User-Agent":
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "일본 桜川市真壁町古城 내일 날씨",
  "hl": "en",
}

response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

location = soup.select_one('#wob_loc').text
weather_condition = soup.select_one('#wob_dc').text
tempature = soup.select_one('#wob_tm').text
precipitation = soup.select_one('#wob_pp').text
humidity = soup.select_one('#wob_hm').text
wind = soup.select_one('#wob_ws').text
current_time = soup.select_one('#wob_dts').text

print(f'Location: {location}\n'
      f'Weather condition: {weather_condition}\n'
      f'Temperature: {tempature}°F\n'
      f'Precipitation: {precipitation}\n'
      f'Humidity: {humidity}\n'
      f'Wind speed: {wind}\n'
      f'Current time: {current_time}\n')

------
'''
Location: Makabecho Furushiro, Sakuragawa, Ibaraki, Japan
Weather condition: Cloudy
Temperature: 79°F
Precipitation: 40%
Humidity: 81%
Wind speed: 7 mph
Current time: Saturday
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using the [Direct Answer Box API](https://serpapi.com/direct-answer-box-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't have to think about how to bypass block from Google or figure out why data from certain elements aren't extracting as it should since it's already done for the end-user. The only thing that needs to be done is to iterate over structured JSON and grab the data you want.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "일본 桜川市真壁町古城 내일 날씨",
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  "hl": "en",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

loc = results['answer_box']['location']
weather_date = results['answer_box']['date']
weather = results['answer_box']['weather']
temp = results['answer_box']['temperature']
precipitation = results['answer_box']['precipitation']
humidity = results['answer_box']['humidity']
wind = results['answer_box']['wind']

print(f'{loc}\n{weather_date}\n{weather}\n{temp}°F\n{precipitation}\n{humidity}\n{wind}\n')

--------
'''
Makabecho Furushiro, Sakuragawa, Ibaraki, Japan
Saturday
Cloudy
79°F
40%
81%
7 mph
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.

Answer (score -1):

I also had this problem.
You should not import like this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

you should import like this

```
from bs4 import *
```

This should work.

Comment: Your approach imports all the dependencies from `bs4` and might even import the dependencies which remain potentially unused. So, ideally, only the required dependencies from a module should be imported.